# How to deal with potential big numbers of Tasks using async/await?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, dapper

I have an Azure Function  that queries a database with Dapper and throws this exceptions  sometimes:

- > System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
- > System.InvalidOperationException: The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken.

Here is what my code is doing:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnectionString))
{
      await conn.OpenAsync();
      List<Guid> ids = await conn.QueryAsync<Guid>("SELECT Id From Table1;");

      var tasksRelations = ids.Select(id => conn.QueryAsync<CsvExport>(
                                      @"SELECT Field1, Field2, ... Field25 
                                        FROM Table2 
                                        WHERE Table1Id = @Id;", 
                                       new { id }));

      var relations = await Task.WhenAll(tasksRelations);
}
```

This works fine when the number of ids is low, but when it's getting bigger I have above exceptions.

Do you have any idea or things to take into to make this code more robust?

Comment: Could it be you have too many task (and thus open connections) running in paralell, resulting in the Server just quitting the oldest connections to get room for new ones? Network operations are not usually something where excessive Paralellisation helps. It varries a bit on the specific operation and how much CPU load is part of hte Protocoll overhead, but it is still a decent general rule.

Comment: This could also be a spotty connection. If you're on wifi or a bad cable, your connection might cut out once in a while. Which you may not notice when doing light tasks, but the odds of running into issues when you're saturating the line with requests increase dramatically.

Comment: I would re-use the same `SqlConnection` object. and manually dispose when db connection is not needed anymore (on close?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to fire off multiple queries against the same connection at the same time. This is a bad idea and there's probably an initial error you've not reported here that says something about having multiple result sets open on the same connection not being supported.

Rather than running so many queries, *simplify* your code to obtain the results you want in a *single* query:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnectionString))
{
      await conn.OpenAsync();
      var relations = conn.QueryAsync<CsvExport>(
                                      @"SELECT Field1, Field2, ... Field25 
                                        FROM Table2 
                                        WHERE Table1Id IN (SELECT Id From Table1);");
}
```

Now you're not having to deal with "big numbers" of tasks and you're only running one query on the connection and so should not generate the errors.

Comment: Sometimes I hate myself, I wonder why I didn't write my query like that :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - you probably want "in" instead of "=" there

Comment: @sellotape - indeed. That's what I was aiming for, somehow neglected it. But hopefully if Swell updated their code and then got a "subquery returned more than one value" error they were able to quickly work around it.